# MYSQL select where date within this day

Tags: mysql, date

MY query looks like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(entryID) 
FROM table 
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Will this count the rows whose `date` values are *within the day* (starting at 12:00; not within 24 hours)? If not, how do I do so?

Comment: I think my solution is `WHERE DAYNAME(date) == CURDATE()`. The problem is that `DAYNAME` returns word form 'Friday'. I need number form so that it can compare with `CURDATE()`.

Comment: It will return all records for yesterday, starting from the beginning of the day, not only those within 24 hours of when it was run.

Comment: `SELECT DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)` returns `2012-03-29`, so `>= '2012-03-29` is all records from yesterday and today.

Comment: If you only want the previous 24 hours, use `NOW()` instead of `CURDATE()`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The following should be enough to get records within the current day:

```
SELECT COUNT(entryID) 
FROM table 
WHERE date >= CURDATE()
```

As Michael notes in the comments, it looks at all records within the last two days in its current form.

The `>=` operator is only necessary if `date` is actually a `datetime` - if it's just a `date` type, `=` should suffice.

Comment: Thanks. You wrote the solution as I was writing my own solution. (I use `DATE(date)` to get just the date part, though).

Comment: @Hope4You - Cool! Just using `=` should be enough then, and actually more correct in case there were ever future dates in there.

Comment: I just remembered now that using `DATE(date)` will stop indexes on row `date` from working. Would it work for me to use `WHERE date >= CURDATE()` even when `date` is `DATETIME`? Will it still only get rows from the very beginning of the day?

Comment: @Hope4You - It should still work for you. I actually wrote the answer thinking `date` might be `datetime`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution:

`SELECT COUNT(entryID)
FROM table
WHERE DATE(date) >= CURDATE()`

Since my `date` column is type `DATETIME`, I use `DATE(date)` to just get the date part, not the time part.

Comment: This solution is very bad performance wise, it have to apply the function to every row in the table and compare after to the current date. With a big table it will arise performance problems.

Answer (score 1):

CURDATE() returns a date like '2012-03-30', not a timestamp like '2012-03-30 21:38:17'. The subtraction of one day also returns just a date, not a timestamp. If you want to think of a date as a timestamp think of it as the beginning of that day, meaning a time of '00:00:00'.

And this is the reason, why this

```
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

and this

```
WHERE date > CURDATE()
```

do the same.

I have another hint: `SELECT COUNT(entryID)` and `SELECT COUNT(*)` give the same result. `SELECT COUNT(*)` gives the database-machine more posibilities to optimize counting, so `COUNT(*)` is often (not always) faster than `COUNT(field)`.

Comment: Good answer - I think you have the operators mixed up in your example though.

Comment: Wouldn't `SELECT COUNT(*)` be slower since `*` means all rows?

Comment: Actually with INNODB a `COUNT(primary_id)` is faster.  `COUNT(*)` can be very slow in a large INNODB table.

Answer (score 0):

`select DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00");`

Output today's start time